# QGIS split all polygon features by dimensions

Tags: qgis, polygon, splitting

I have a shapefile of 16370 polygon features (see below). I want to split **all** features in features with a maximum size of 25x25 meters (still including all attributes).

I am aware ArcGIS Pro is currently having such an option (https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/editing/divide-a-polygon-by-a-value.htm), but I have no access to the program. Does anyone have an idea to achieve something similar?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save alot of time by doing:

1. Create grid
2. Intersect the grid with your polygons